# How does Node.js handle unclosed HTTP responses

Tags: node.js, http, express

Consider a trivial [express](http://expressjs.com/) app:

```
app.get '/hang', (req, res) ->
  console.log 'Request ', n
  n += 1
  # res.send 200
```

Whoops, I've accidentally commented out the [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send), oh well, let's see what happens!

If I hit `/hang` with my browser it just sits there spinning, which makes sense. Without the `send` we're not closing the connection (correct assumption?). Let's see what happens if we hit `/hang` with [a bunch of simultaneous connections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html):

```
$ ab -n 1000 -c 1000 http://localhost:3000/hang

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

The app manages to print out a couple of hundred `Request n`s and then just gets stuck.

My questions are:

1. What's happening here?
2. Will these connections eventually be closed? Or:
3. Is my server now hosed until it's restarted?

---

Additional:

You can pass `-r` to `ab` to have it ignore socket errors.
When I use that I start to see `ab` listing some requests as being completed:

```
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

Could this be the connections being closed by node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's happening here?

The connections just sit idly doing nothing. They do cost memory to keep open, but negligible CPU.

> Will these connections eventually be closed?

Yes, I believe the OS's network layer will eventual close them with a timeout error. Either the client or server could trigger this depending on configuration (keepalives and timeout values in particular).

> Is my server now hosed until it's restarted?

No, you can cleanly recover from a certain number of these without a restart. So if in a real server a bug caused 1 out of every 1000 requests to hang without a response, for a given traffic load, it would be manageable. It's basically a function of hung connections per unit of traffic and traffic load to determine whether this is a survivable error or will cascade out of control until your server exhausts resources.